# Can I have a "type of types" in C++?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm quite new to C++, but I've been trying to diversify my skillset a bit during the lockdown.
I'm attempting to write a node-based sound processing tool using SFML. I want to have a struct to contain all of my nodes' inputs and outputs. However, I obviously can't connect any type together. I'm looking to do something similar to what Blender does with its node types.
The following screen recording shows what I mean: the green output type is incompatible with other input types.
[image: This screen recording]

I thought that a `struct NodeInOut` could be a useful solution to this problem: I'd have a type that I assign whenever I create a new Node, and in the logic for connecting Nodes together I make sure that incompatible types aren't connectable. However, I'll need to pass in a type whenever I create a new Node definition.

My idea for the Node class is that it would be structured a bit like this hastily made diagram.

[image: this hastily made diagram]

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this, or how to structure it differently such that this isn't an issue?

I haven't written any code yet besides the SFML boilerplate stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have a "type of types".

However, notice the user connects nodes at runtime. Thus this is a runtime problem, not something you can solve at compile time.

In other words, simply use runtime values that contain whatever types your nodes accept/send and compare them as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that that isn't an approach that I had considered. Is there a way that I can use class inheritance though? I don't really want to write the same code (for drawing, updating etc.) for every node I want to add.

Comment: @WalrusGumboot Of course, for the code itself of each node, you want to reuse whatever you can. You can do that with inheritance (to share code in a hierarchy), as well as other approaches (for instance, composition like in the Entity-Component-System pattern).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, something like this should work:

- Specific nodes inherit from an abstract `class Node`.
- `class Node` contains pure virtual functions to list the input/output points:

  ```
  virtual std::size_t InputCount() const = 0;
  virtual const Input &GetInput(std::size_t i) const = 0;
  Input &GetInput(std::size_t i) {return const_cast<Input &>(std::as_const(*this).GetInput(i));}

  virtual std::size_t OutputCount() const = 0;
  virtual const Output &GetOutput(std::size_t i) const = 0;
  Output &GetOutput(std::size_t i) {return const_cast<Output &>(std::as_const(*this).GetOutput(i));}
  ```

  And probably something like `virtual void Update() = 0;`, `DrawGui`, etc.
- Classes derived from `Node` have `Input` and `Output` objects as members, and override `GetInput` and `GetOutput` to return those members.

  <sup>(Bonus: you might be able to do generate the functions automatically using a reflection library such as [`magic_get`](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).)</sup>
- `class Input` will have to somehow point to the `Output` it's connected to, probably by storing a pointer (`std::weak_ptr`?) to `Node` owning the connected `Output`, along with the index of that `Output` in the node.
- `class Output` should at least contain `float value;` (or something else, depending on what values you want to support). Maybe you will want to store a list of connected `Input`s in there (where each element would be a pointer to `Node` plus the index of the `Input` in it).

Comment: I'm not really a fan of that solution, firstly because of the `const_cast`s (though after more reflection I can't think of a way to correct it...), and secondly because of the `weak_ptr`: why not a simple `Output *`? Also the output should remember a `vector` of `Input *` instead of the connected Node**s** and Input index**es** (OP wants to connect to multiple inputs...).

Comment: @rajdakin *"`weak_ptr`: why not a simple `Output *`?"* If it's a `weak_ptr`, then removing a node is easy: you just delete it, and nodes that were connected to it disconnect automatically. But if it's a plain pointer, then you have to iterate over all connected Nodes and disconnect them manually (which is not that easy, given that `GetOutput` and other virtual functions won't work properly in the destructor). [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] *"output should remember a vector of `Input *` instead of ..."* It depends on what OP needs the list for, if they need it at all. I don't see an immediate need to have this list to begin with.

Comment: indeed, a `weak_ptr` would be better if OP allows the use of `shared_ptr`s.  On a side note, what do you think about a non-virtual class `Node`, which contains a `vector` of `Input`s and another of `Output`s (which you can then access in the destructor)? It would then also need to contain a variable which represents a function that takes in a `Node &` (the virtual `Update` function, but as a user-managed function, see also [this Fluent C++ article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2020/05/15/runtime-polymorphism-without-virtual-functions/))... It would allow to remove the `const_cast`s.

Comment: @rajdakin Sure, it might work. Consider posting a separate answer about it. The potential problems is having more than one virtual-like function, and storing state in the nodes that can be used by all those functions (if you only need a single function `Update`, you could make it a `std::function` and store the state in there, but if you need more than one function, you'll need something else).

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments below [HolyBlackCat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63655748/8657480), here is my alternative:

- Each nodes are a member of the (final, not virtual) `Node` class
- This `Node` class has an `std::vector<Input>` and an `std::vector<Output>`, which represents each input and output of the node (they could probably be made const if you try hard enough)
- You add a private variable called `update` which has type `std::function<void(Node &)>` or equivalent (so you could have lambdas, for example), which is a user-defined update method to set the outputs depending on the inputs, and a public function called `Update`, which is a function that calls the `update` of this node and the `Update` of the following nodes (since they need to update too)
- Then for the `Output`s you need to have a function to set the value (maybe a templated function? Then you check if the type is correct and get a compatible type, maybe use `std::variant`s to store the value), and the list of all `Input`s connected to it (so an `std::vector<Node*, unsigned>` maybe? Or you can also replace the `Node*` by a `std::weak_ptr<Node>`)
- As for the inputs you need to be able to connect them to one `Output` so either an `Output*` or an `std::weak_ptr<Output>` should work, but since you need to be able to have constants you can either:

  1. Also have an `std::variant` to store the default value, or
  2. You can create new "invisible" `Node`s with no input and one output for each dangling inputs, or
  3. You create an invisible `Node` for each visible ones, which has no input and as many outputs as there are inputs for the target Node (and connect them one-to-one).

This is maybe (probably) not the best solution, but at least it should work.